# Arabic numerals in swing.JTextField java

Tags: java, swing, internationalization

Peace be upon you all.

javas.swing.JTextField does not support **numerals** of other languages like arabic, hebrew, chinese on **input**. I have researched a lot on this but I couldnt find a solution.

I really need functionality as my whole application is based on Javax.swing components.

Need solution guys!!!

> > Put a JTextField on a simple plain GUI. Go to the regional settings and select Arabic (saudia arabia) as locale and customize the 'digit substitution' as 'national' (System wide arabic numerals applied). Now go to the java app and type numbers in the textfield. The number would not be in arabic but in english. This is the problem..

Comment: It should support any printable Unicode character. Are they just missing from the font you are using?

Comment: What is specifically not working? Arabic numbers are unicode symbols, so if fonts present they should be shown. And what concerning Hebrew numbers? Do you mean that system does not understand automatically that א means 1 and ו means 6?

Comment: you are wrong Java (then GUI for example JTextField) supporting all knows Charsets / Locales / Fonts, hmmm please what's your question

Comment: Put a JTextField on a simple plain GUI. Go to the regional settings and select Arabic (saudia arabia) as locale and customize the 'digit substitution' as 'national' (System wide arabic numerals applied).

Now go to the java app and type numbers in the textfield. The number would not be in arabic but in english. This is the problem..

Comment: First check that it works correctly with some Windows app, e.g. Notepad. If it does try TextField instead of JTextField.

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine with all the other windows applications. Basically it works with TextField which is from awt library. The problem is persistent with all the swing components in Java. and my problem is that I HAVE TO USE SWING =(.

Comment: hmm ... sounds weird, did you find anything in the bug parade? Can't really imagine that a bug like that goes unnoticed for long. But then who knows, those usa-centric swing developer insisted on ignoring f.i. the German keyboard layout as well, for ages ;-)

Comment: haha...exactly..that what I was concerned about. I even tried jdk 1.7 but not fixed. On the other hand the whole java.awt library supports multilingual numeral support. I guess I should seriously consider reporting this bug to Oracle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: this is *not* an answer to the question - just a comment with a code snippet

In SwingX we had an [issue with NumberFormat not showing arabic digits](http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-1062) properly. Nothing helped except allowing client code access to the internals of JXMonthView so they could manually adjust the unicode range to use for the digits:

```
    private void adjustFormatSymbols(Locale locale, DecimalFormat df) {
        if ("ar".equals(locale.getLanguage())) {
            DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
            // set the beginning of the range to Arabic digits
            dfs.setZeroDigit('\u0660');
            df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually this is probably the only way that we have to do it...However it has certain disadvantages..but solves the problem in a bigger context.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could try this (at least for searching for clues):

register a KeyListener with both the AWT TextField and Swing JTextField and see what is received when you type "1" on the keyboard.

Then, if you get different codes, you could possibly check if you can write a general event handler that gets all keys and replace keys 0-9 with the matching code in arabic locale.

Not a perfect solution, but it might work.

Comment: I have tried this and sort of implemented this too. But this kind of overridden solutions are generally not accepted in enterprise solutions, u know, due to standards.

This is very strange that Java does not provide complete internationalization support in Swing components. =S

Comment: Maybe you should consider reporting a bug to Oracle?

Comment: That probably is the only option left. Thanks.

Comment: @Zaki Imtiaz recently, Hovercraft implemented a DocumentFilter doing the replace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470260/typing-arabic-numbers-in-jtextfield

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an answer, but here's an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that may suggest a way forward. See also [*Supported Locales*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/locale.doc.html).

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886323 */
public class ArabicNumbers extends JPanel {

    private static final Locale arabic = new Locale("ar", "SA");
    private static final DecimalFormat format =
        (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(arabic);
    private static final JFormattedTextField field =
        new JFormattedTextField(format);
    private ComponentOrientation arabicOrientation =
        ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(arabic);

    public ArabicNumbers() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(arabic));
        field.applyComponentOrientation(arabicOrientation);
        field.setValue(123.45);
        this.add(field);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ArabicNumbers");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ArabicNumbers().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This changes only the orientation of the text. I need to have arabic numerals  while I write instead of English 12345.

Comment: Exactly. It's just a starting point, as I am only familiar with [western Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals). I've updated the code to use an instance of `DecimalFormatSymbols`, localized to "ar_SA". You might try customizing it to use Hindi numerals.

Comment: hmm ... probably missing something: I only see the "text" part in arabic (probably, cant judge :-), not the digits, 123.45 appears just so