# Changing Java Locale

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-8

i am trying to set the Locale by this way

```
Locale ar = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-arab").build();
Locale.setDefault(ar);
```

I am trying here to change the numbering system from the Latin to Arabic system 
when I call for example

```
int i = 1000;
System.out.println(i);
```

it doesn't change the numbering System it still Latin until I use `NumberFormat`

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(ar);
String s = nf.format(i);
System.out.println(s);
```

In this way it printed correctly in the arabic numbers .
I need a way to display all digits in arabic so please help.

Comment: When you have to "format" all numbers, you will have to extend all number processing with the number formatting below - System.out.println does no formatting by itself.

Comment: ok i have textfields and i need the user to enter arabic numbers not latin numbers did you get the idea @Smutje

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6470345/1386551

Comment: it didn't work for me and i have a lot of number entry in my program let's say this solution works for the entry process .
but it doesn't when loading numbers from Data Base  did you understand me @blackbishop

Comment: there must be a way to force java to use different numbering System but how I don't Know

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(i);
```

is by definition a locale-insensitive operation which isn’t affected by your change of the default `Locale`.

You may resort to

```
System.out.printf("%d%n", i);
```

which does respect the locale.

---

To elaborate it a bit more:

#### println

The [documentation of `PrintStream.println(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-int-) specifies:

> Prints an integer and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(int)` and then `println()`.

whereas [`print(int)` is specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-int-) as

> Prints an integer. The string produced by `String.valueOf(int)` is translated into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.

which leads us to [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-):

> Returns the string representation of the int argument.
>
> The representation is exactly the one returned by the `Integer.toString` method of one argument.

[`Integer.toString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-)

> Returns a `String` object representing the specified integer. The argument is converted to signed decimal representation and returned as a string, exactly as if the argument and radix 10 were given as arguments to the `toString(int, int)` method.

[`toString(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-):

> […]
>   If the first argument is negative, the first element of the result is the ASCII minus character `'-'` (`'\u002D'`). If the first argument is not negative, no sign character appears in the result.
>
> The remaining characters of the result represent the magnitude of the first argument. If the magnitude is zero, it is represented by a single zero character `'0'` (`'\u0030'`); otherwise, the first character of the representation of the magnitude will not be the zero character. The following ASCII characters are used as digits:
>
> > `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
>
> These are `'\u0030'` through `'\u0039'` and `'\u0061'` through `'\u007A'`. …

So at the end of this long road we see a specification leaving no room for locale-specific results.

#### printf

Compare to the [specification of `PrintStream.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) (note that the is even an [overloaded method taking a `Locale` as first argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)):

> A convenience method to write a formatted string to this output stream using the specified format string and arguments.
>
> An invocation of this method of the form `out.printf(format, args)` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>
> > `out.format(format, args)`
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> format - A format string as described in [Format string syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

The [Format String Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) is quite a big specification. We have to look at the [section “Byte, Short, Integer, and Long”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dnint):

> The following conversions may be applied to `byte`, `Byte`, `short`, `Short`, `int` and `Integer`, `long`, and `Long`.
>
> `'d'` `'\u0064'`  Formats the argument as a decimal integer. The [localization algorithm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#L10nAlgorithm) is applied.
>
> […]

The [localization algorithm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#L10nAlgorithm) happens to be described right above that section:

> #### Number Localization Algorithm
>
> After digits are obtained for the integer part, fractional part, and exponent (as appropriate for the data type), the following transformation is applied:
>
> 1. Each digit character *d* in the string is replaced by a locale-specific digit computed relative to the current locale's [zero digit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getZeroDigit--) *z*; that is *d -*  `'0'`  *+ z*.
> 2. If a decimal separator is present, a locale-specific [decimal separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getDecimalSeparator--) is substituted.
> 3. If the `','` (`'\u002c'`) flag is given, then the locale-specific [grouping separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getGroupingSeparator--) is inserted by scanning the integer part of the string from least significant to most significant digits and inserting a separator at intervals defined by the locale's [grouping size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#getGroupingSize--).
> 4. If the `'0'` flag is given, then the locale-specific [zero digits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getZeroDigit--) are inserted after the sign character, if any, and before the first non-zero digit, until the length of the string is equal to the requested field width.
> 5. If the value is negative and the `'('` flag is given, then a `'('` (`'\u0028'`) is prepended and a `')'` (`'\u0029'`) is appended.
> 6. If the value is negative (or floating-point negative zero) and `'('` flag is not given, then a `'-'` (`'\u002d'`) is prepended.
> 7. If the `'+'` flag is given and the value is positive or zero (or floating-point positive zero), then a `'+'` (`'\u002b'`) will be prepended.
>
> If the value is NaN or positive infinity the literal strings "NaN" or "Infinity" respectively, will be output. If the value is negative infinity, then the output will be "(Infinity)" if the `'('` flag is given otherwise the output will be "-Infinity". These values are not localized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to set the default locale for all `Swing` components in your program :

```
Locale ar = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-arab").build();
JComponent.setDefaultLocale(ar);
```

Comment: it didn't success sorry @blackbishop

Comment: that's effective only for localizing swing components (and only for those that were created after setting the locale)